# can TypeScript restrict keyof to a list of properties of a particular type?

Tags: typescript, generics

so, I want to write a generic method. For the sake of the question, let's say I want to concatenate 2 string properties from 2 different objects of the same type.

```
function concat<T>(target1: T, target2: T, key: keyof T): string {
  return target1[key] + target2[key];
}
```

The above fails to compile because the compiler has no indication that I want to restrict `key` to only be the list of properties of type `string`.

**Is this not currently supported in TypeScript?**

I know I can do runtime checks, but I want *compile-time* checks for this one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want a three parameter generic here. One for each input, and one for the key.

```
type CommonKey<A, B> = keyof A & keyof B

function concat<A, B, K extends CommonKey<A, B>>(
  target1: A,
  target2: B,
  key: K
): string {
  return `${target1[key]}${target2[key]}`
}
```

This defines the key as both a key of A and B, meaning that it must satisfy both.

---

To constrain it further to only string values, you need to use a mapped type with a condition to test for its type.

```
// This type returns all keys that have a value of type string
type StringKeyOf<T> = {
    // for all keys in T
    [K in keyof T]:

        // if the value of this key is a string, keep it. Else, discard it
        T[K] extends string ? K : never

// Get the union type of the remaining values.
}[keyof T]

// Only allow common keys of both objects.
type CommonKey<A, B> = StringKeyOf<A> & StringKeyOf<B>

function concat<
    A,
    B,
    K extends CommonKey<A, B>
>(target1: A, target2: B, key: K): string {
    return `${target1[key]}${target2[key]}`
}
```

Now this will give a type error, because `age` is a number.

```
concat(
    { name: 'a', age: 12 human: 'maybe?' },
    { name: 'b', age: 8, dog: true },
    'age' // Type error

)
```

Comment: oh my, this is cool. Let me give it a shot in my use case and I'll be sure to mark it as the answer...

Comment: thanks for the awesome answer. And it does limit the `key` parameter to only string parameters. The one thing that is still bugging me is that inside `concat()` the compiler has no idea that `target[key]` is of type `string`. This is a contrived example I gave. In my real-world case, I would prefer the compiler warns me (well, more accurately, anybody else coming after me on the team...) that we're doing something wrong. I know I can force it to be `string`. I was just hoping that TS would support something like this a bit more cleanly.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that too. I'm not sure there's anyway around that, sadly. It's a lot for the compiler to keep track of. But you can rest assured that the external interface is type safe, and that you know for _sure_ those are strings. So the programmer knows more than the compiler in this case. And that's are when casting is wholly appropriate. `a: string = target1[key] as any`